# Child route not showing in Vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nested-routes

I've following object in Vue router.

```js
{
  path: "/books",
  name: "books",
  component: Books,
  children: [
    {
      path: ":id",
      name: "books.detail",
      component: BookDetail,
    }
  ]
}
```

Within `Books.vue` component, there're `<router-link>` that upon clicking each; it should go to its detail view.

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'book.detail', params: { id: 5 }}">
  <h2>Book Name</h2>
</router-link>
```

Similarly in `App.vue` I've following `<router-view>`.

```html
<div class="books">
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

When I click `<router-link>` the path gets updated but the respective `BookDetail` Page doesn't show up.

It's first time I am integrating routers within a project and couldn't figured out how to solve it, even going in depth reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Books.vue` there needs to be an additional `<router-view>` to show the nested route component.  Without it, you would get the behavior you describe.

*Books.vue*

```html
<template>
  <div>
    Books
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Or if you didn't want nested routing, define the detail page as a separate route:

```js
{
  path: "/books",
  name: "books",
  component: Books
},
{
  path: "/books/:id",
  name: "books.detail",
  component: BookDetail
}
```

(Note: There's also a typo in the `<router-link>` (`book` instead of `books`) but since you were able to see the correct route path, maybe that's just a typo in your post.)

Comment: Thank you for answering, I really appreciate it. Yes, I added `<router-view>` in `Books.vue` component as well, but it shows books list and book detail concurrently when I click upon a book item. Any solution for this?

Comment: You're welcome.  Yes, the 2nd half of my answer, because that means you don't really want a nested route, which is for showing both concurrently.  In that case, also remove the `<router-view>` from *Books.vue*.

Comment: Okay, I thought I can do it this way.